# How to implement an interface using class member?

Tags: c#, interface

I have this dog class:

```
public class Dog : IBarkable
{
      public void Bark()
      {
            Console.WriteLine("Woof!");
      }
}
```

and i have this human class:

```
public class Human : IBarkable
{
      private Dog _myDog = new Dog();

      public void Bark()
      {
            _myDog.Bark();
      }
}
```

Is there any way that i won't have to implement each function explicitly?
somthing like this:

```
public class Human : IBarkable (_myDog)
{
      private Dog _myDog = new Dog();
}
```

thanks!

Comment: There is no automatic interface implementation delegation, that's one of the reasons (if not the main reason) why 'composition over inheritance' is sometimes painful to do. You have to do it manually.

Comment: This is a strong sign that `Human` shouldn't implement `IBarkable` and it should instead have a method/property that returns an `IBarkable` object (in this case the dog).

Comment: @Servy: Isn't it better to have methods on Human which is used to interact with the humans dog? You don't want to to run loose by just handing it out to anyone who asks for it. (law of demeter)

Comment: @jgauffin It wouldn't be exposing anything in any way that it currently isn't.  If the `IBarkable` implementations did something other than directing all of them to the dog, then the human is actually doing something, changing behavior, possibly restricting some aspect of the behavior that the dog exposes.  Additionally it would be important to expose it as an `IBarkable` object, not a `Dog`.  Generally the reason for the composing object to implement the interface here is if it *doesn't* want to just forward everything unconditionally to a single object.

Comment: Im not saying that inheritance is better, but that composition without a property is better (if you want to have better encapsulation/control).

Comment: I didn't want to write my actual problem here, so I used the human-dog example, some of you 'brainiacs' didn't get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though there is no features for implementing delegating members in visual studio, resharper provides one.

You're looking for [Generating Delegating Members](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Code_Generation__Delegating_Members.html) of resharper.

Answer (score 1):

From the logical point of view a Human can not bark. So deriving a human from this interface makes no sense. Instead you should provide at least a getter method returning your dog object.

Comment: And why should he break Law of Demeter by doing as you suggest?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to expose a "pet" of the human, a more flexible and technically correct way would be to abstract the Bark method and make the human expose certain aspects of the "pet".  As far as API design goes, it's not very intuitive to have a method "Bark" on a human object.  Also to consider: what if the human as a cat, parrot, monkey, and an elephant for pets?  In this case, your code as it is becomes difficult to maintain (which I suspect is why you want to "auto-implement" interface methods).

I would suggest a slight refactor of your code into something more like this:

```
public interface ISpeakingAnimal {

    void Speak();

} // end interface IAnimal

public interface IHasPets {

    List<ISpeakingAnimal> Pets {get; set;}

    bool HasPets();

} // end interface IHasPets

public class Dog : ISpeakingAnimal {

    public void Speak() {
        Console.WriteLine("Woof");
    }
} // end class Dog

public class Cat : ISpeakingAnimal {

    public void Speak() {
        Console.WriteLine("Meow");
    }
} // end class Cat

public class Human : IHasPets {

    public Human() {
        Name = "The Doctor";
        Pets = new List<ISpeakingAnimal>();
    } // end constructor

    public string Name {get; set;}

    public List<ISpeakingAnimal> Pets {get; set;}

    public bool HasPets() {
      return Pets.Any();
    } // end method HasPets

} // end class Human

//Somewhere in your executing code
Human person1 = new Human();
ISpeakingAnimal dog = new Dog();
ISpeakingAnimal cat = new Cat();
person1.Pets.Add(dog);
person1.Pets.Add(cat);

for(int i = 0; i<person1.Pets.Count; i++) {
    person1.Pets[i].Speak();
} // end for loop
```

This encompases several SOLID software development practices, which you can read more about here if you're interested: http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/SOLID.aspx

This design allows you to add new types of pets at any point without having to make changes to Human, or the other animals. and you can add methods to human to interact with it's pets without changing the actual nature of what a human is (since we don't typically bark ;)).